# Evaluating letters in a string using switch-cases and booleans in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement, boolean

I'm on course and we've recently started learning Java.
I've got a task identify pangrams using switch-cases and booleans. The task states:

> 1. Create a String ‘sentence’ with the value “Sixty zippers were quickly picked from the woven jute bag.”
> 2. Create 26 Boolean variables named a to z
>
>    a. Boolean a, b, … y, z;
>
>    b. a, b, … y, z = true;
> 3. Create a loop that will iterate over each letter of the sentence
>
>    a. Be careful of the iterator you use within your loop as the letter
>    ‘i’ will already be taken!
> 4. Using switch-cases and the Booleans you made, identify the letter and set the corresponding Boolean to true.
> 5. Once the sentence has been fully processed, evaluate the value of each Boolean:
>
>    a. Should all of them be true, print the message ‘the sentence
>    “” is a pangram!’
>
>    b. Should any of them be false, print the message ‘the sentence
>    “” is not a pangram!’

I'm not sure if it's just the wording of the task that's tripping me up, but I'm not sure how to execute it.
This is what I've got at the moment:

```
String sentence = "Sixty zippers were quickly picked from the woven jute bag.";
        Boolean a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z;
        
        a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = i = j = k = l = m = n = o = p = q = r = s = t = u = v = x = y = z = true;
        
            for (int letter = sentence.length() - 1; letter <= 0; letter++) {
                
                int character = sentence.charAt(letter);
                
                switch(character) {
                case a:
                case b:
                case c:
```

When I do the case like this, obviously it won't convert, so how would I evaluate each character?

Comment: `case 'a':`, not `case a:`.

Comment: `for (int letter = sentence.length() - 1; letter <= 0; letter++) {` **yikes**. I assume you meant `for (int letter = sentence.length() - 1; letter >= 0; letter--) {`

Comment: There is something wrong with the task itself. The boolean values are never set to false. So it's going to always tell you that the sentence is a pangram.

Comment: Not a good use case for `switch` and `boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the for loop is not correct. To iterate over the characters in order:

```
for (int letter = 0; letter < sentence.length(); letter++) {
```

When fetching a character from the string, convert it to lower case (otherwise, you'd need a separate `case` for both `'a'` and `'A'`):

```
char character = Character.toLowerCase(sentence.charAt(letter));
```

The switch statement:

```
switch(character) {
    case 'a': 
        a = false; 
        break; // needed to avoid fall-through to case 'b'
    case 'b': 
        b = false; 
        break; 
    ...
```

Now you can test if all variables were set to false:

```
boolean isPangram = !a && !b && ... && !z;
```

The code would be simpler and clearer if the variables were set to `false` in the beginning and to `true` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot wrong in an incomplete solution.  This looks like a school assignment so I'm not writing code but here are some things you should address.

- Do not initialize your boolean flags to true. Set them to true when
  you encounter that character.

  - you may want to change the type of the flags to be primitive boolean and/or you will want to initialize them to false.
- You've defined `character` as an `int` but it should really be a `char`

  - note that using an `int` will work due to implicit casting but it may prove confusing.
- The cases names should be in single quotes to indicate they are characters rather
  than the variables you defined at the beginning.
- within each case, set the appropriate flag and break to prevent fall-through assignments
- the for-loop is set up wrong.  You are starting at the end and increment so it will stop immediately.

  - start at the beginning (i.e. initialize `letter` to 0)
  - change the condition to cover the length of the String
  - the incrementor is fine.